# How to implement Android Sqlite Union rawQuery?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using the following code to search the column "English". There is another column called "BANGLA". How I should modify the code so that both "ENGLISH" and "BANGLA" columns are searched simultaneously and returned as combined result?

```
public List<Bean> getWords(String englishWord) {
        if(englishWord.equals(""))
            return new ArrayList<Bean>();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ENGLISH + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + ENGLISH + " LIMIT 100 ";

        SQLiteDatabase db = initializer.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{"%" + englishWord + "%"});

            List<Bean> wordList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String english = cursor.getString(1);
                String bangla = cursor.getString(2);
                String status = cursor.getString(3);
                wordList.add(new Bean(id, english, bangla, status));
            }

            return wordList;
        } catch (SQLiteException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

I modifed the `String sql` to

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ENGLISH + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + ENGLISH + " LIMIT 100 " + " UNION ALL " + " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + BANGLA + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + ENGLISH + " LIMIT 100";
```

However, this does not work. I am getting this error:

```
ORDER BY clause should come after UNION ALL not before (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM words WHERE en_word LIKE ? ORDER BY en_word LIMIT 100  UNION ALL  SELECT * FROM words WHERE bn_word LIKE ? ORDER BY en_word LIMIT 100
```

Comment: This does not work as in?

Comment: What is the exact error that you're getting? Could it be that you're not adding a second selection argument? `cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{"%" + englishWord + "%", "%" + englishWord + "%"});`

Comment: I am getting  I am getting `wordList == null`. I added the second selection argument as suggested but still does not work.

Comment: The error is `ORDER BY clause should come after UNION ALL not before (code 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move ORDER BY and LIMIT to the end like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ENGLISH LIKE ?
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM tull
WHERE BANGLA LIKE ?
ORDER BY ENGLISH LIMIT 100
```

However this will order only by english and limit to 100 rows total. Did you need 100 rows per language? If you want to order by both language you can alias the columns and order by that alias:

```
SELECT *, ENGLISH AS TEXT FROM tull
WHERE ENGLISH LIKE ? OR BANGLA LIKE ?
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, BANGLA AS TEXT FROM tull
WHERE BANGLA LIKE "" 
ORDER BY TEXT LIMIT 100;
```

You'll still need to add the second selection argument as jyanks mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thank you. This solve my problem.